# Unable to interact with JavaFX Controls - possible .fxml layout issue

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml, scenebuilder

I used to have a RootLayout border pane that had an fx:includes Anchor pane with my controller on it. I'm trying to combine these two into one .fxml file but I'm having an issue trying to interact with the upper half of my application (buttons, combo box, etc are unclickable). I'm assuming there's a problem with my organization or maybe even a height over lapses but I'm not seeing it and this is my first javaFX application ever. If I open the .fxml in JavaFX Scene Builder, I'm only able to see the Border Pane in the hierarchy.

Here is the old setup with two .fxml files

Old RootLayout.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="500.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
    <fx:include fx:id="Tabs" source="Tabs.fxml" />
   </children>
</BorderPane>
```

Old Tabs.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="asset.view.TabsController">
    <children>
        <AnchorPane prefHeight="125.0" prefWidth="500.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="375.0">
            <children>
                <GridPane AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="35.0">
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="95.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="74.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="125.0" minWidth="125.0" prefWidth="125.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                    <children>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleInputRecord" text="Submit" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
                            <GridPane.margin>
                                <Insets left="5.0" />
                            </GridPane.margin>
                        </Button>
                        <Label text="Employee ID" />
                        <Label text="Asset ID" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="inputEmployeeIdField" minWidth="125.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="inputAssetIdField" minWidth="125.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                    </children>
                </GridPane>
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
        <MenuBar prefWidth="500.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
            </menus>
        </MenuBar>    
        <AnchorPane prefHeight="375.0" prefWidth="500.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="125.0">
            <children>
                <TabPane nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" prefHeight="375.0" prefWidth="500.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
                    <tabs>    
                        <Tab text="Overview">
                            <content>
                                <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5761872909698996" focusTraversable="true">
                                    <items>
                                        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                                            <children>
                                                <TableView fx:id="overviewTable" layoutX="-12.5" layoutY="58.0" prefHeight="320.0" prefWidth="175.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                                    <columns>

                                                        <TableColumn fx:id="overviewAssetIdColumn" minWidth="60.0" text="Asset ID" />
                                                        <TableColumn fx:id="overviewEmployeeIdColumn" minWidth="70.0" text="Employee ID" />
                                                        <TableColumn fx:id="overviewAssetNameColumn" minWidth="80.0" text="Asset Name" />
                                                        <TableColumn fx:id="overviewInventoryStatusColumn" minWidth="50.0" text="Status" />
                                                    </columns>
                                                    <columnResizePolicy>
                                                        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                                                    </columnResizePolicy>
                                                </TableView>
                                            </children>
                                        </AnchorPane>
                                        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="298.0" prefWidth="400.0">
                                            <children>
                                                <Label layoutX="7.0" layoutY="6.0" text="Overview Details:" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="5.0" />
                                                <GridPane layoutX="14.0" layoutY="33.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="30.0">
                                                    <columnConstraints>
                                                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                                        <ColumnConstraints />
                                                        <ColumnConstraints />
                                                        <ColumnConstraints />
                                                        <ColumnConstraints />
                                                        <ColumnConstraints />
                                                        <ColumnConstraints />
                                                    </columnConstraints>
                                                    <rowConstraints>
                                                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                    </rowConstraints>
                                                    <children>
                                                        <Label text="Asset ID" />
                                                        <Label text="Asset Name" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                                                        <Label text="Manufacturer" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                                                        <Label text="Equipment Type" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                                                        <Label text="Employee ID" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                                                        <Label text="Employee Name" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                                                        <Label text="Check Out Date" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
                                                        <Label fx:id="overviewAssetIdLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                                                        <Label fx:id="overviewAssetNameLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                                                        <Label fx:id="overviewManufacturerLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                                                        <Label fx:id="overviewTypeLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                                                        <Label fx:id="overviewEmployeeIdLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                                                        <Label fx:id="overviewEmployeeNameLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                                                        <Label fx:id="overviewCheckOutDateLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
                                                        <Label fx:id="overviewIdLabel" text="" GridPane.columnIndex="7" />
                                                    </children>
                                                </GridPane>
                                                <HBox layoutX="215.0" layoutY="259.0" spacing="5.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0">
                                                    <children>
                                                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleOverviewRefresh" text="Refresh" />
                                                    </children>
                                                </HBox>

                                            </children>
                                        </AnchorPane>
                                    </items>
                                </SplitPane>
                            </content>
                        </Tab>

                        <Tab text="Employees">
                            <content>
                                <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.42618729096989966" focusTraversable="true">
                                    <items>
                                        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                                            <children>
                                                <TableView fx:id="employeeTable" layoutX="-12.5" layoutY="58.0" prefHeight="298.0" prefWidth="175.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                                    <columns>
                                                        <TableColumn fx:id="employeeFirstNameColumn" minWidth="102.0" text="First Name" />
                                                        <TableColumn fx:id="employeeLastNameColumn" minWidth="114.0" text="Last Name" />
                                                    </columns>
                                                    <columnResizePolicy>
                                                        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                                                    </columnResizePolicy>
                                                </TableView>
                                            </children>
                                        </AnchorPane>
                                        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="298.0" prefWidth="393.0">
                                            <children>
                                                <Label layoutX="7.0" layoutY="6.0" text="Employee Details:" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="5.0" />
                                                <GridPane layoutX="14.0" layoutY="33.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="30.0">
                                                    <columnConstraints>
                                                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                                        <ColumnConstraints />
                                                        <ColumnConstraints />
                                                        <ColumnConstraints />
                                                    </columnConstraints>
                                                    <rowConstraints>
                                                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                    </rowConstraints>
                                                    <children>
                                                        <Label text="Employee ID" />
                                                        <Label text="First Name" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                                                        <Label text="Last Name" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                                                        <Label text="Status" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                                                        <Label fx:id="employeeEmployeeIdLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                                                        <Label fx:id="employeeFirstNameLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                                                        <Label fx:id="employeeLastNameLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                                                        <Label fx:id="employeeStatusLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                                                        <Label fx:id="employeeIdLabel" text="" GridPane.columnIndex="4" />
                                                    </children>
                                                </GridPane>
                                                <HBox layoutX="215.0" layoutY="259.0" spacing="5.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0">
                                                    <children>
                                                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleNewEmployee" text="New..." />
                                                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleEditEmployee" text="Edit..." />
                                                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleDeleteEmployee" text="Delete" />
                                                    </children>
                                                </HBox>
                                            </children>
                                        </AnchorPane>
                                    </items>
                                </SplitPane>
                            </content>
                        </Tab>    
                    </tabs>
                </TabPane>
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

New Combined Rootlayout.fxml and Tabs.fxml now named RootLayoutTabs.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="500.0"  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="asset.view.TabsController">
    <children>
        <AnchorPane prefHeight="125.0" prefWidth="500.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="375.0">           
            <children>

        <MenuBar prefWidth="500.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
            </menus>
        </MenuBar>          

                <GridPane AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="35.0">
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="95.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="74.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="125.0" minWidth="125.0" prefWidth="125.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                    <children>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleInputRecord" text="Submit" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
                            <GridPane.margin>
                                <Insets left="5.0" />
                            </GridPane.margin>
                        </Button>
                        <Label text="Employee ID" />
                        <Label text="Asset ID" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="inputEmployeeIdField" minWidth="125.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="inputAssetIdField" minWidth="125.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                    </children>
                </GridPane>

                    </children>
        </AnchorPane>
        <AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
            <children>
                <AnchorPane prefHeight="375.0" prefWidth="500.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="125.0">
                    <children>
                        <TabPane nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" prefHeight="375.0" prefWidth="500.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
                            <tabs>
                                <Tab text="Overview">
                                    <content>
                                        <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5761872909698996" focusTraversable="true">
                                            <items>
                                                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                                                    <children>
                                                        <TableView fx:id="overviewTable" layoutX="-12.5" layoutY="58.0" prefHeight="320.0" prefWidth="175.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                                            <columns>

                                                                <TableColumn fx:id="overviewAssetIdColumn" minWidth="60.0" text="Asset ID" />
                                                                <TableColumn fx:id="overviewEmployeeIdColumn" minWidth="70.0" text="Employee ID" />
                                                                <TableColumn fx:id="overviewAssetNameColumn" minWidth="80.0" text="Asset Name" />
                                                                <TableColumn fx:id="overviewInventoryStatusColumn" minWidth="50.0" text="Status" />
                                                            </columns>
                                                            <columnResizePolicy>
                                                                <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                                                            </columnResizePolicy>
                                                        </TableView>
                                                    </children>
                                                </AnchorPane>
                                                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="298.0" prefWidth="400.0">
                                                    <children>
                                                        <Label layoutX="7.0" layoutY="6.0" text="Overview Details:" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="5.0" />
                                                        <GridPane layoutX="14.0" layoutY="33.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="30.0">
                                                            <columnConstraints>
                                                                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                                                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                                                <ColumnConstraints />
                                                                <ColumnConstraints />
                                                                <ColumnConstraints />
                                                                <ColumnConstraints />
                                                                <ColumnConstraints />
                                                                <ColumnConstraints />
                                                            </columnConstraints>
                                                            <rowConstraints>
                                                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                            </rowConstraints>
                                                            <children>
                                                                <Label text="Asset ID" />
                                                                <Label text="Asset Name" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                                                                <Label text="Manufacturer" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                                                                <Label text="Equipment Type" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                                                                <Label text="Employee ID" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                                                                <Label text="Employee Name" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                                                                <Label text="Check Out Date" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
                                                                <Label fx:id="overviewAssetIdLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                                                                <Label fx:id="overviewAssetNameLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                                                                <Label fx:id="overviewManufacturerLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                                                                <Label fx:id="overviewTypeLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                                                                <Label fx:id="overviewEmployeeIdLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                                                                <Label fx:id="overviewEmployeeNameLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                                                                <Label fx:id="overviewCheckOutDateLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
                                                                <Label fx:id="overviewIdLabel" text="" GridPane.columnIndex="7" />
                                                            </children>
                                                        </GridPane>
                                                        <HBox layoutX="215.0" layoutY="259.0" spacing="5.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0">
                                                            <children>
                                                                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleOverviewRefresh" text="Refresh" />
                                                            </children>
                                                        </HBox>

                                                    </children>
                                                </AnchorPane>
                                            </items>
                                        </SplitPane>
                                    </content>
                                </Tab>
                                <Tab text="Employees">
                                    <content>
                                        <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.42618729096989966" focusTraversable="true">
                                            <items>
                                                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                                                    <children>
                                                        <TableView fx:id="employeeTable" layoutX="-12.5" layoutY="58.0" prefHeight="298.0" prefWidth="175.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                                            <columns>
                                                                <TableColumn fx:id="employeeFirstNameColumn" minWidth="102.0" text="First Name" />
                                                                <TableColumn fx:id="employeeLastNameColumn" minWidth="114.0" text="Last Name" />
                                                            </columns>
                                                            <columnResizePolicy>
                                                                <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                                                            </columnResizePolicy>
                                                        </TableView>
                                                    </children>
                                                </AnchorPane>
                                                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="298.0" prefWidth="393.0">
                                                    <children>
                                                        <Label layoutX="7.0" layoutY="6.0" text="Employee Details:" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="5.0" />
                                                        <GridPane layoutX="14.0" layoutY="33.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="30.0">
                                                            <columnConstraints>
                                                                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                                                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                                                <ColumnConstraints />
                                                                <ColumnConstraints />
                                                                <ColumnConstraints />
                                                            </columnConstraints>
                                                            <rowConstraints>
                                                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                            </rowConstraints>
                                                            <children>
                                                                <Label text="Employee ID" />
                                                                <Label text="First Name" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                                                                <Label text="Last Name" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                                                                <Label text="Status" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                                                                <Label fx:id="employeeEmployeeIdLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                                                                <Label fx:id="employeeFirstNameLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                                                                <Label fx:id="employeeLastNameLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                                                                <Label fx:id="employeeStatusLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                                                                <Label fx:id="employeeIdLabel" text="" GridPane.columnIndex="4" />
                                                            </children>
                                                        </GridPane>
                                                        <HBox layoutX="215.0" layoutY="259.0" spacing="5.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0">
                                                            <children>
                                                                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleNewEmployee" text="New..." />
                                                                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleEditEmployee" text="Edit..." />
                                                                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleDeleteEmployee" text="Delete" />
                                                            </children>
                                                        </HBox>
                                                    </children>
                                                </AnchorPane>
                                            </items>
                                        </SplitPane>
                                    </content>
                                </Tab>                                  
                            </tabs>
                        </TabPane>
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
    </children>
</BorderPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had an extra Anchor pane that it didn't like. I removed the following code;

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="125.0" prefWidth="500.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="375.0">
<children>
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: You have some other weird stuff in your FXML.  You are setting the children of a BorderPane with is a bit undefined (I think), instead you should set top/bottom/left/right nodes.  When you set the children of the border pane directly, SceneBuilder doesn't even display the hierarchy for your layout correctly in the hierarchy panel.  You are really just laying out top to bottom I think, so Using a VBox rather than a BorderPane as your root might be more appropriate.